# Set default value for the public exponent e And get n as the modulus of key pairs

Tags: c++, cryptography, rsa, crypto++

I'm using [cryptopp](http://www.cryptopp.com/) to generate key pairs and i'm wondering if there is a way to set a default value like 65537 for the public exponent **e**.

```
GenerateRSAKey(keyLength, privFilename, pubFilename, seed);
```

Second question is that how can i get the **n** as the modulus of generated key pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation about Raw RSA, http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Raw_RSA. I think it covers everything you are asking about.